# conflict between utf-8 and iso-8859-1 in IE 10

Tags: utf-8, internet-explorer-10, iso-8859-1

i am getting execption while loading page in IE 10

> HTML1114: Codepage utf-8 from (HTTP header) overrides conflicting
>   codepage iso-8859-1 from (META tag)

Comment: because of this exception web page is not loading....it is displaying some special characters

Comment: Because of this webpage is not loading for first time in ie10, downloads a text file with some special characters.

Comment: The webserver is at fault. It is reporting the page's charset as UTF-8, but the page itself is reporting its own charset as ISO-8859-1 instead. Those are conflicting charsets if there are any non-ASCII characters on the page. A fix needs to be done on the webserver side.

Comment: thanks for the input Remy Lebeau .If we need to fix in webserver side should we declare any character set as default or should we remove the character set what we have set?.